# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in class doesn't works

Tags: php

```
//...

<?php
class Essentials {

  //...
  //...

  static $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}


//...
?>
```

Php writing an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE) in /Users/Dima/Desktop/localhost/YouLose/lib/lib.php on line 17
```

What's the matter? Outside the class it works. In php $_SERVER is "superglobal" as I know

Comment: Have you read a manual?

Comment: Sorry, manual of what?

Comment: Of php oop features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better initialize it inside the **constructor**:

```
<?php
class Essentials {


    static $root;


    public function __construct() {
        self::$root =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    }
}

?>
```